# Why is matplotlib.cm.jet not recognized while importing matplotlib alone?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to get *matplotlib.cm.jet* using the code below:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.cm.jet)
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ae42efdc0f9b> in <module>
----> 1 light = matplotlib.cm.jet

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'cm'
```

But, if I include *import matplotlib.pyplot as plt*, it works well!!!!

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(matplotlib.cm.jet)
```

The output:

```
<matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap object at 0x00000136974123D0>
```

**Why does it happen?**

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior - the colormap is loaded in both cases.

Comment: @Mr.T - hmm, I reproed in 3.4.3, and did not repro in 3.5.1

Comment: Never doubted that this problem exists - just saying I cannot reproduce it in 3.5.1. Bizarr, seemingly they forgot to include `cm` in the directory.

Comment: In 3.4.3 that is.

Comment: When you do `from matplotlib import pyplot`, pyplot's initialization is executed, which adds some shortcuts to matplotlib.  Depending on the version, the backend and on whether matplotlib is run interactively, different initializations are performed.  (And please note that [`jet` is a colormap with some undesirable properties](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented pretty well by Mr. T and BigBen, it is an issue due the version of the Matplotlib I am using (3.3.1, also reproduced in version 3.4.3).

> (...) seemingly they forgot to include cm in the directory. – Mr. T

An update to version 3.5.1 solves the problem.

Thank you guys!